# How to continuously check the status of a serial port

Tags: c#, serial-port

So far when I run my app, I can detect any port that is connected to my PC but let's say, I disconnected the port and reconnected while I'm running the program so How can I detect the port while the program is running ? Like Tera Term or Docklight. 
One of my guess is running a timer but I was wondering if someone could help me out please. because I'm not very familiar with port's functions.

```
    // Fonction Configuration Port Terminal
    void ConfigurationTerminal()
    {
        if (Serial_Port_1.IsOpen == false)
        {

            // Port Configuration
            Serial_Port_1.PortName = (string)cbn_Port.SelectedItem;
            Serial_Port_1.BaudRate = Baudrate;
            // Parity Configuration 
            switch (OptionalParity)
            {
                case 0: Serial_Port_1.Parity = Parity.None; break;
                case 1: Serial_Port_1.Parity = Parity.Even; break;
                case 2: Serial_Port_1.Parity = Parity.Odd; break;
                default: Serial_Port_1.Parity = Parity.None; break;
            }

            Serial_Port_1.DataBits = DataBits;
            switch (OptionalStopBit)
            {
                case 0: Serial_Port_1.StopBits = StopBits.One; break;
                case 1: Serial_Port_1.StopBits = StopBits.OnePointFive; 
                break;
                case 2: Serial_Port_1.StopBits = StopBits.Two; break;
                default: Serial_Port_1.StopBits = StopBits.One; break;
            }
            Serial_Port_1.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            Serial_Port_1.Handshake = Handshake.None;

            // Set the read/write timeouts
            Serial_Port_1.ReadTimeout = 500;
            Serial_Port_1.WriteTimeout = 500;
            try
            {
                Serial_Port_1.Open();
                BackColor = Color.Green;
                Txt_DataSend.Text = "I'm ready to receive the data.\r\n";
                FlagRdyToSend = "1";
                Serial_Port_1.Write(FlagRdyToSend);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                BackColor = Color.Red;
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            BackColor = Color.Green;
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is a Device Arrived WMI event you could subscribe to.  It seems to me to be easier to just use a timer as you suggest though

Comment: Trying to detect a connect or disconnect is usually a waste of time, especially when you're only testing the local end.  Something bad could happen on the remote end.  What you probably really want to test for is a failure to respond to a query, rather than the connection status.

Comment: By the way, Visual Studio is an IDE (essentially a code editor) capable of producing code for C, C++, C#, Visual Basic.NET, F#, Typescript, Javascript, amongst others. As such, I've removed it from your question.